# Request for Hyperbolic $ \sech \,x $ inclusion in MathJax

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax, newcommand

MathJax does not work for hyperbolic  $ \sech \,x$... Can it be now included? Thanks in advance.

EDIT1:

From user1729's comment suggestion, they work okay:

$$\operatorname{sech}(x) $$

$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech} $$

$$\sech (y)$$

Comment: Somewhat related older discussions: [Can custom TeX/MathJax commands be defined by default for a site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/28066) and [$\LaTeX$ shortcuts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25283). (Perhaps also [Personalised $\LaTeX$ commands for users](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19141) and [Specific Latex commands for user's account](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11870).)

Comment: Do you know that you can define it manually? `\operatorname{sech}(x)` renders as $\operatorname{sech}(x)$.

Comment: Also, you can use `\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}`$\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}$ to define it everywhere in your post. So typing `sech(x)` now gives $\sech(x)$. (There is a way, or used to be a way, to define commands for a whole page, but I can't remember it at the moment.)

Comment: $\csch$ doesn't work either, but $\coth$ does.
It's not just Mathjax: those commands aren't in Latex either.

Comment: Thanks. First one works, but the second one ( *Declare..) does n't seem to. May be all hyperbolic functions and their inverses should be made readily available without user definition.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31077/how-to-define-string-remap-in-mathjax/31078#31078) mentions various way to define things locally (in one post) - using \DeclarMathOperator, \newcommand, \def, \let. @user1729 The scope of a macro is now only a single post (or a single comment) and not the entire page - this was changed in January 2019, the change was [announced in this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/the-scope-of-newcommand-is-the-entire-page).

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator` should work, in the sense that it worked above for me...

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the links. It's good that the scope was changed; it's silly otherwise (as the links demonstrate!).

Comment: @1729 both work, may be was some error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make my comments into an answer:

Firstly, you can define it manually, so `\operatorname{sech}(x)` renders as $\operatorname{sech}(x)$. A more fancy way is to put `\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}` somewhere in your post, and then `\sech` will work everywhere in the post.

For example, I'll declare the operator (invisibly) here: $\DeclareMathOperator{\sech}{sech}$

And it renders nicely here: $\sech(x)$

(Click on "edit", below, to see my code.)

---

There are other ways to do this. For example, you can use `\newcommand` rather than `\DeclareMathOperator`: `\newcommand{\csch}{\operatorname{csch}` $\newcommand{\csch}{\operatorname{csch}}$ gives $\csch(x)$.

(One way *not* to do it is to use `\mathrm{csch}` rather than `\operatorname{csch}`. For example, `\operatorname{csch}x` $\operatorname{csch}x$ is correctly spaced while `\mathrm{csch}` $\mathrm{csch}x$ is not. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/48459/13669) for more details.)