# Does MathJax really not recognize cosec?

Tags: bug, mathjax

I tried to get the trig function cosec in MathJax, but it comes out as $\cosec$. In contrast, it works perfectly well for sec: $\sec$. Of course, one can always use \operatorname{cosec} as a workaround ($\operatorname{cosec})$; but this seems clumsy. The shorter form csc works: $\csc$. Perhaps the designers of MathJax simply don't like cosec and think that we should all switch to csc.

Comment: This is not a bug wrt Stack Exchange software, it is a feature of mathjax, over which Stack Exchange has no control.  Mathjax is not unique to some stack exchange sites.

Comment: It also recognizes $\sinh x$, but not $\sech x$.

Comment: Related (a bit): [Request for Hyperbolic $ \sech \,x $ inclusion in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31144).

Answer (score 5):

No, you're right that mathjax doesn't recognize `$\cosec(x)$`: $\cosec(x)$, but it recognizes `$\csc(x)$`: $\csc(x)$ for use when you want to denote cosecant(x).  It is likely due to the fact that `\sin(x), \cos(x), \tan(x), \sec(x), \cot(x)` all have three-letter operator-names, and so the choice of operator for cosecant, in mathjax, similarly has a three-letter operator: `\csc(x)`.

Even though one can speak of $\csc(x) = \frac 1{\sin x}$, mathjax does not recognize `$\arccsc(x)$`: $\arccsc(x)$, though it recognizes `$\csc^{-1}(x)$`: $\csc^{-1}(x)$. But nor does it recognize `$\arcsec$`: $\arcsec$, nor `$\arccot$`: $\arccot$.

But we do have `$\arcsin, \arccos, \arctan$`: $\arcsin, \arccos, \arctan$.

Now, a work around, if you're needing to use cosecant a lot in one post, is to write `\DeclareMathOperator{cosec}{cosec}` before needing to use cosec.  Then, you can use it as you like, as you expected you could, by writing `\cosec(x)`.  I display the results immediately below.  You can click on "edit" to see that it does indeed work.

$\DeclareMathOperator{cosec}{cosec}$

$\cosec(x)$